# Reward video not showing, and not giving reward. Unity 3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, admob

My advertisement is shown in game when the player fires a laser round at the box collider which is supposed to trigger a reward video ad then give the player 500 coins. The problem is that the ad does not show and give rewards even though it says its loaded in the console(see below). I am only using adMob so I shouldn't need to change any settings for mediation(I believe). I have tried to upload this onto my phone as well and still get nothing. Any ideas on fixing this?

Side question -  I am also wondering if this is just an issue with using test ads?

Console

```
Dummy .ctor
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
GoogleMobileAds.Common.DummyClient:.ctor() (at Assets/GoogleMobileAds/Common/DummyClient.cs:28)
GoogleMobileAds.GoogleMobileAdsClientFactory:BuildRewardBasedVideoAdClient() (at Assets/GoogleMobileAds/Platforms/GoogleMobileAdsClientFactory.cs:57)
System.Reflection.MethodBase:Invoke(Object, Object[])
GoogleMobileAds.Api.RewardBasedVideoAd:.ctor() (at Assets/GoogleMobileAds/Api/RewardBasedVideoAd.cs:43)
GoogleMobileAds.Api.RewardBasedVideoAd:.cctor() (at Assets/GoogleMobileAds/Api/RewardBasedVideoAd.cs:25)
RewardVideoPic:Start() (at Assets/_Scripts/RewardVideoPic.cs:28)
RewardVideoPic:Start() (at Assets/_Scripts/RewardVideoPic.cs:17)

Dummy CreateRewardBasedVideoAd
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
GoogleMobileAds.Common.DummyClient:CreateRewardBasedVideoAd() (at Assets/GoogleMobileAds/Common/DummyClient.cs:124)
GoogleMobileAds.Api.RewardBasedVideoAd:.ctor() (at Assets/GoogleMobileAds/Api/RewardBasedVideoAd.cs:44)
GoogleMobileAds.Api.RewardBasedVideoAd:.cctor() (at Assets/GoogleMobileAds/Api/RewardBasedVideoAd.cs:25)
RewardVideoPic:Start() (at Assets/_Scripts/RewardVideoPic.cs:28)
RewardVideoPic:Start() (at Assets/_Scripts/RewardVideoPic.cs:17)

Dummy LoadAd
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
GoogleMobileAds.Common.DummyClient:LoadAd(AdRequest, String) (at Assets/GoogleMobileAds/Common/DummyClient.cs:134)
GoogleMobileAds.Api.RewardBasedVideoAd:LoadAd(AdRequest, String) (at Assets/GoogleMobileAds/Api/RewardBasedVideoAd.cs:121)
RewardVideoPic:Start() (at Assets/_Scripts/RewardVideoPic.cs:25)

Dummy IsLoaded
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
GoogleMobileAds.Common.DummyClient:IsLoaded() (at Assets/GoogleMobileAds/Common/DummyClient.cs:108)
GoogleMobileAds.Api.RewardBasedVideoAd:IsLoaded() (at Assets/GoogleMobileAds/Api/RewardBasedVideoAd.cs:127)
RewardVideoPic:ShowAd() (at Assets/_Scripts/RewardVideoPic.cs:40)
RewardVideoPic:OnTriggerEnter(Collider) (at Assets/_Scripts/RewardVideoPic.cs:34)

Dummy ShowRewardBasedVideoAd
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
GoogleMobileAds.Common.DummyClient:ShowRewardBasedVideoAd() (at Assets/GoogleMobileAds/Common/DummyClient.cs:144)
GoogleMobileAds.Api.RewardBasedVideoAd:Show() (at Assets/GoogleMobileAds/Api/RewardBasedVideoAd.cs:133)
RewardVideoPic:ShowAd() (at Assets/_Scripts/RewardVideoPic.cs:42)
RewardVideoPic:OnTriggerEnter(Collider) (at Assets/_Scripts/RewardVideoPic.cs:34)
```

Code

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;

public class RewardVideoPic : MonoBehaviour {

    public Text CoinText;
    //  public laserScript AutoFire;
    private bool reward = false;
    private RewardBasedVideoAd rewardBasedVideo;


    void Start()
    {
        // Get singleton reward based video ad reference.
        this.rewardBasedVideo = RewardBasedVideoAd.Instance;

        string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917";

        // Create an empty ad request.
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();

        // Load the rewarded video ad with the request.
        this.rewardBasedVideo.LoadAd(request, adUnitId);
        rewardBasedVideo.OnAdRewarded += HandleRewardBasedVideoRewarded;

    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if(other.tag == "laserBullet")
        {
            ShowAd();
        }
    }

    private void ShowAd()
    {
        if (rewardBasedVideo.IsLoaded())
        {
            rewardBasedVideo.Show();
        }
    }

    public void HandleRewardBasedVideoRewarded(object sender, Reward args)
    {
        reward = true;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (reward == true)
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Coins", PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Coins") + 500);
            CoinText.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Coins").ToString();
            reward = false;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Never mind for some reason its working now...

Comment: please add your solution as an answer and mark it as accepted

Comment: I didn't do anything though... Should I just erase the question?

Comment: I think you can only flag it but yes, if the question has no answer it should be deleted

Comment: Actually maybe you can help me? Sometimes it plays the video and other times not. Its like its having trouble loading, I will let it sit for a while, but sometimes that doesn't even help. Then when I play it, it wont load a second time. Thanks!

Comment: I think, after creating app in admob, need wait a while, before it starts working.